# "essential for doing", "essential to doing": when should I use which?

Tags: grammar

I'm confused about the following examples that [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/essential) gives:

> Formulating new strategies **is essential for preparing** the corporation to meet and sustain future needs.

uses the pattern *something is essential for something*, and

> Knowledge, skills, and creativity **are essential to creating** high-value products.

uses the pattern *something is essential to do something*.

I guess both "to" and "for" above function as prepositions. Does that mean it's still grammatical and natural when I use those interchangeably?

For example,

> Formulating new strategies **is essential to preparing** the corporation to meet and sustain future needs.

> Knowledge, skills, and creativity **are essential for creating** high-value products.

I'm aware those are different from

> It is essential to research and protect your patent.

which is similar to the pattern *it is important to know …*

However, I can't tell the reason under the hood. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Splitting hairs I suspect.   All of your examples seem fine to me and mean the same. It would seem that essential for+creating, and essential to+creating are both possible.  There are many examples of each, and both are pretty close number-wise in terms of usage. [see google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=essential+for+creating%2C+essential+to+creating&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the general rule (there will be exceptions) is as follows:

1. You can use either "essential for" or "essential to" if it is followed by a noun
2. You use "essential for" if it is followed by a [gerund](https://www.lexico.com/definition/gerund) ("ing") form of a verb
3. You use "essential to" if it is followed by a verb.

Examples:

1. Books are essential for/to education (noun)
2. Books are essential for educating students (gerund)
3. Books are essential to educate students (verb)

Unfortunately, I have to disagree with the example in the Cambridge dictionary as I would have said "Knowledge, skills, and creativity are essential to **create** high-value products".

Comment: While I agree with your general rules, you are right that there can be exceptions. I think this may be a case of common usage rather than any specific grammar rule. Google ngram [shows that both are in use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=essential+to+create%2Cessential+to+creating&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). Essential to create is more common though.  With "essential to create", this could be because the "to" in  "essential to" could be viewed as a preposition rather than an infinitive marker.