# Use it to/for doing

Tags: gerunds, to-infinitive

What is the difference in meaning between the following sentences, and which one is more idiomatic?

1. I use this app **for keeping** track of what I eat.
2. I use this app **to keep** track of what I eat.
   Thank you.

Comment: No difference in meaning, and neither is more idiomatic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["For doing" vs. "To do"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58801/for-doing-vs-to-do). Also ["To do" or "For doing"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65702/to-do-or-for-doing) and ["To do this" or "For doing this" to start explaining something?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84997/) and ["essential for doing", "essential to doing": when should I use which?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/311270/) and [https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/311270/](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/315698/), among others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sentences have a similar meaning, but the second one is more idiomatic and commonly used.

The difference in meaning between the two sentences is subtle. The first sentence suggests that using the app is a habitual action, whereas the second sentence simply states that the app is being used for the purpose of tracking what is being eaten. However, the distinction is very slight and may not be noticeable in all contexts.

Overall, the second sentence is more commonly used and considered more idiomatic because it uses the preposition "to" before the verb "keep track," which is the standard way of expressing this idea in English.